# How do I set a weight to SF Symbols for iOS 13?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, sf-symbols

I have this

```
Image(systemName: "arrow.right")
```

But how do I make it bold, semibold etc?

I am using the new SwiftUI.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

When using the `font` modifier, set a weight to the font you're passing.

For example, if you want to use one of the default text styles (which I recommend, since they adapt to the user's Dynamic Type setting), you can do it like this:

```
Image(systemName: "arrow.right")
  .font(Font.title.weight(.ultraLight))
```

If you want to specify a font size, you can do it like this:

```
Image(systemName: "arrow.right")
  .font(Font.system(size: 60, weight: .ultraLight))
```

Comment: I tried this, but this seems to change the size and not the weight (bold, light, semibold ect). Unless i misunderstood?

Comment: My bad, it was I who misunderstood. I've updated my answer.

Comment: For default size this would be `Font.body.weight(.ultraLight)` (for example inside navigationBarItems) ([all font weights](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/font/weight))

Answer (score 84):

For UIKit, symbols can be configured as follows:

```
UIImage(systemName: "arrow.right",
        withConfiguration: UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 16, weight: .bold))
```

Answer (score 29):

## SwiftUI 1.0

I just wanted to also mention how to change the weight along with a custom font size.

```
HStack(spacing: 40) {
    Image(systemName: "moon.zzz")
        .font(Font.system(size: 60, weight: .ultraLight))
    Image(systemName: "moon.zzz")
        .font(Font.system(size: 60, weight: .light))
    Image(systemName: "moon.zzz")
        .font(Font.system(size: 60, weight: .regular))
    Image(systemName: "moon.zzz")
        .font(Font.system(size: 60, weight: .bold))
}
```

[image: Example of Font Size and weight]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer I think as the question is dealing with SwiftUI and it sets the `.system` font not the `.title` ← which could interfere with other styling.

Answer (score 28):

## UIKit -- Swift 5 -- Xcode 11

If you **only** want to set the weight (so you don't mess up auto icon sizing), do this:

```
let configuration = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(weight: .semibold)
UIImage(systemName: "trash", withConfiguration: configuration)
```

Answer (score 27):

You can also wrap the `Image` with `Text`. With that you can use and assign the `fontWeight()` to `Text`:

```
Text(Image(systemName: "xmark"))
    .fontWeight(.semibold)
```

Comment: This is the best solution for SwiftUI as the font size doesn't have to be set.

Comment: It's a nice solution but available from iOS 16 only

Comment: It has been working for me since 2020 at least from iOS 14 up.

Answer (score 15):

**UIKit SWIFT 5.x**

To set their attributes: create a configuration then pass it in as a parameter:

```
let imageConfig = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 22, weight: .black, scale: .large)
let image = UIImage(systemName: "delete.right", withConfiguration: imageConfig)
```

Answer (score 10):

For iOS 16.0, macOS 13.0, tvOS 16.0, watchOS 9.0, you can use `fontWeight()` directly on the `Image()`.

```swift
Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
    .fontWeight(.semibold)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the best answer for iOS 16.0+

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 13.4, Swift 5.X

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI


public extension Image {
    
    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    static func buildSystemImage(named systemName: String, weightConfiguration: UIImage.SymbolWeight) -> Image? {
        guard let imageConfig = UIImage(systemName: systemName, withConfiguration: UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(weight: weightConfiguration)) else { return nil }
        return Image(uiImage: imageConfig)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
if let systemImage = Image.buildSystemImage(named: "arrow.left", weightConfiguration: .semibold) {
    // Your code.                
}
```